# MySQL string data truncated in group_concat and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL that works fine but truncates the serialized data on string fields long more than 1024bytes. I tried to change the mysql variable group_concat_max_len, but nothing has changed. Are there any other session variables that could be involved in?

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 100000;
SELECT CONCAT(AREA,';',
              COLORE,';',
              CAST(PERCENTUALE AS CHAR(20)),';',
              CAST(TRASPARENZA AS CHAR(20)),';',
              DATE_FORMAT(DATA_MISURA,'%Y%m%d'),';', 
              ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( CAST(X AS CHAR(20)), ' ', CAST(Y AS       
                CHAR(20)) ) ORDER BY PROGRESSIVO_VERTICE SEPARATOR ';')
                FROM   plan_poligoni 
                WHERE ID_IMM = PP_GEN.ID_IMM 
                  AND SCHEDA = PP_GEN.SCHEDA 
                  AND PROGRESSIVO = PP_GEN.PROGRESSIVO 
                  AND IF(DATA IS NULL,'',DATA) = IF(PP_GEN.DATA IS NULL,'',PP_GEN.DATA)),'|') 
AS SERIALIZED_POLYGONS
FROM plan_poligoni AS PP_GEN
WHERE SCHEDA=1 
  AND ID_IMM = 1111 
  AND PROGRESSIVO_VERTICE = 1
GROUP BY ID_IMM, SCHEDA, PROGRESSIVO;
```

Comment: I'm thinking about using mysql COMPRESS() and then decompress it in JS using Zlib.js but, sincerly, I'm not sure this is the right way to use JSON.

Comment: Believe it is also constrained by MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET

Comment: I cannot modify MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET because of my hosting. It seems a variable that cannot be modified with SET SESSION, but only with SET GLOBAL I'm finding strange that I'm the only with this problem...

Comment: what is the type of the column where you try to save these data?

Comment: Also, may be you should rethink the way you organize your data? E.g. one main table + another table that keeps relevant data for every entry in the first table on by-row basis.

Comment: @Ashalynd the field is computed, as you can see from sql. What I'm thinking is that I'm wrong using mysql to serialize data instead of PHP.

Comment: What is MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET set to? I would expect it to be FAR greater.

Comment: Yes @Kickstart, MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET is far greater. That's not the problem.

Comment: Can you set up some test data on sql fiddle to have a look at? The only thing I can currently think causing a problem is that you are passing the SQL using a call that can only cope with a single SQL statement at a time.